# TypeScript Cannot find module react-scripts lerna webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, lerna, react-scripts

I am trying to setup a new project with lerna, react-scripts, webpack and sass.

My directory structure is the following

```
myApp
  /packages
    /myReactApp -> this is a react create app application
      /tsconfig.json
      /package.json
    /components -> this is built using webpack
      /dist => is is autogenerated
        /index.js
        /index.d.ts
        /elements
          /Button.d.ts
      /tsconfig.json
      /package.json
      /webpack.config.js
      /src/elements/Button
                    /Button.tsx
                    /Button.scss
    /tsconfig.json
    /tsconfig.settings.josn
  /package.json
```

in my /packages/myReactApp/src/components/SomeComponent.js import a component from the 'components' package.

`import { Button } from 'components';`

the /packages/myReactApp/package.json file from myReactApp has a dependency of the 'components' package

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "src/index.tsx",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "cra-template-typescript": "1.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "types": "^0.1.1",
    "components": "1.0.0" => this is the dependency of the other package
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
==> "myApp:start": "yarn run start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
}
```

the /packages/myReactApp/tsconfig.json file looks like this

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.settings.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../components"
    }
  ],
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

the /packages/components/package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "components",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",=> this file is generate by webpack and is in the right location
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts", => this file is generate by webpack and is in the right location
  "scripts": {
    "delete": "rimraf dist",
    "start": "yarn run delete && webpack --env.mode development --watch",
    "myApp:start": "yarn run start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ....
  }
}
```

/packages/components/webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.css', '.scss'],
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    { loader: 'css-loader' },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader' },
                ],
            },
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
        ],
    }
};
```

/packages/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    { "path": "myReactApp" },
    { "path": "components" }
  ]
}
```

/packages/tsconfig.settings.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "composite": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "skipLibCheck": false
  }
}
```

the error is the following:

```
/Users/.../projects/.../MyApp/packages/myReactApp/src/components/SomeComponent/myComponent.tsx
TypeScript error in /projects/.../myApp/packages/myReactApp/src/components/SomeComponent/myComponent.tsx(3,26):
Cannot find module 'components'.  TS2307
```

The index.js and index.d.ts files are generated corectly in the components package,
however the main react app doesn't know about it.

my guess is that I run a rimraf /dist when I start the webpack server
and lerna start the two projects in paralel, and myApp starts first and it doesn't know about the definition from the dependency package.

I tried combining the `"composite": true` option with the `references` option but it didn't work. maybe I am missing something.

I also tried to use tsc instead of webpack to run the /packages/components package. It worked very well, but the problem with tsc is that I cannot import scss files (or other type of files). So it might also be a webpack configuration issue.

EDIT: If I change the import from `import { Button } from 'component';` to `import { Button } from 'component/';` it will start working, even if I remove the / again. (Or I can remove the entire line, let the webpack recompile and add it back)

Thank you for reading this long post. Please let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the react server started watching files before the dependency packaged generated the dist folder.

The solution was to change the lerna command that executed the scripts, like this (in the main package.json file):

`"myApp:start": "lerna run --stream --no-sort admin:start", ...`

so that option `--no-sort` did the trick. 
This option is not in the lerna readme file :(